# Is it mandatory to sign-extend when adding two different-sized buses?

Tags: adder, optimization

I am trying to optimize a critical path in my design. The bottle-neck of the path is a 32-bit ADDER between a 32-bit bus and a sign-extended 16-bit bus. At first, when I didn't realize it was signed, I thought I could simply reduce the ADDER to 17 bits (for the possible carry of the lower 16) and zero-extend the 16-bit bus, but then I realized the 16-bit value is sign-extended to 32 bits.

This got me stuck on trying to reduce the ADDER to 16/17 bits (for improved timing), and I couldn't come up with some neat trick to do so.

Is there any way I can reduce the size of the ADDER to sign-add a 32-bit bus with a 16-bit bus, or am I simply *forced* to sign-extend and add the whole 32 bits?

Comment: If you can afford an extra clock of latency, just pipeline the 32-bit addition across two (or more) clock cycles. Many years ago, when FPGAs were much slower, I did a 24-bit addition 2 bits at a time, pipelined to produce a result every clock cycle.

Comment: @DaveTweed If only... My problem is exactly that I'm trying to squeeze logic into one cycle, hence looking for any reduction possible. The fallback is of course expanding the path over multiple cycles if there will be no alternative...

Answer (score 1):

Supposing your numbers are in 2 complement form.
Lets call XY the 32 bits number (X being the 16 most significan bits, Y the 16 least significant bits).
Lets call Z the 16 bits number and S its sign bit

you can compute Y+Z (which gives you a carry bit C)

in parrallel, you can compute X+1 and X-1 (you can use incrementer/decrementer, or a 16 bit adder, it won't change the delay as you already have a 16 bit adder in paralell.

Then, based on the carry C and the sign S, you can select between X-1, X and X+1 using multiplexers. (X-1 if S=1 and C=0, X+1 if S=0 and C=1, X if S=C).

So instead of having the delay of a 32bit adder, you have the delay of a 16 bit adder + a 4 to 1 multiplexer (at the cost of a more complex circuit).

You can even go one step further : as incrementing/décrementing is faster than a general addition (even if you use an adder for it, it should still settle more quickly), so you have a bit of time left on the most significan bits side.

So you could already use a first layer of 2 to 1 multiplexes to choose the 2 values between (X-1, X and X+1) that correspond to the sign bit S, that way you only need 2 to 1 multiplexes once you get the value of C.

With that option, your delay is reduced to the one of a 16 bits adder + a 2 to 1 multiplexer

Comment: That is a very creative and nice solution!!! Thank you so much for your answer! Unfortunately (for me...), according to the timing sheet I'm working with, the time of a 16 ADDER + 2:1 16 bit MUX is greater than a 32 ADDER... So in that case, as optimizing the timing is the key point, I might as well just stay with 32 bit ADDER. I will wait a bit for others to answer but I will accept this in a while because even I can't use it, it definitely answers the question in the title: *"Is it mandatory to sign-extend when adding two different-sized buses?"* to which you answered "not at all!". Thanks!

Comment: Well, it is possible that your 32 adder uses a similar technique inside.
To add WX+YZ (each letter 16 bits), you can use 3 16 bits adders : X+Z (wich gives carry C), W+Y, and W+Y+1 (many adders have a "+1" input (carry input) to chain multiple adders). Then you use 16 *  2:1 multiplexers to choose between W+Y and W+Y+1 based on C.

In theory, it is a little bit slower than my second method : you get a 16 bit adder WITH cary input + 2:1 multiplexer instead of 16 bit adder WITHOUT cary input + 2:1 multiplexer. But if you are using discreate ICs, changing IC will cost more time than input cary

Comment: Yep I might give it another check or even just try your solution and run some timing analysis. Thanks again, this is exactly the kind of trickery I had in mind. With a bit more time I would probably get to it myself xP